template error in rendering: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.existingSecret
I have a starfulset.yaml file with this parameters:
{{- if not .Values.ignoreChartChecksums }}
    checksum/secrets: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secrets.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
    checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
{{- end }}

When the helm lint start i get error of:

[ERROR] templates/: template: statefulset.yaml:77:29: executing "//statefulset.yaml" at <include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secrets.yaml") .>: error calling include: template: //charts//templates/_helpers.tpl:81:14: executing "minio.secretName" at <.Values.auth.existingSecret>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.existingSecret

In the _helpers.tpl line 81 i have this code:
{{- define "minio.secretName" -}}
{{- if .Values.auth.existingSecret -}}
{{- printf "%s" (tpl .Values.auth.existingSecret $) -}}

What is wrong in my yamls definition, is there any issue that I'm missing ? why the value is not found although it's exist in the helm values yaml. please help

Do you mean .Files.Get instead of include here?  include executes a defined template function in your code.  It's not clear to me what would call minio.secretName in the code you've shown.
